# Group Array by Object key where key is an object

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, vuejs3, lodash

I want to group this array by rg_ext objectKey, where every key inside of rg_ext is equal matches with rg_ext in other object.

like this..

```
const RoomsPrices = ref([
  {
    rg_ext: {
      class: 5,
      quality: 0,
      sex: 0,
      bathroom: 2,
      bedding: 3,
      family: 0,
      capacity: 2,
      club: 0,
    },
    room_name: "2 Bedrooms Double Suite (full double bed)",
    cost: 10000,
    priceid: 15464,
  },
  {
    rg_ext: {
      class: 3,
      quality: 0,
      sex: 0,
      bathroom: 2,
      bedding: 2,
      family: 0,
      capacity: 3,
      club: 0,
    },
    room_name: "3 Bedrooms Double Suite (full double bed)",
    cost: 14000,
    priceid: 12464,
  },
  {
    rg_ext: {
      class: 3,
      quality: 0,
      sex: 0,
      bathroom: 2,
      bedding: 2,
      family: 0,
      capacity: 3,
      club: 0,
    },
    room_name: "3 Bedrooms Double Suite (full double bed)",
    cost: 14000,
    priceid: 12464,
  },
  {
    rg_ext: {
      class: 5,
      quality: 0,
      sex: 0,
      bathroom: 2,
      bedding: 3,
      family: 0,
      capacity: 2,
      club: 0,
    },
    room_name: "2 Bedrooms Double Suite (full double bed)",
    cost: 16300,
    priceid: 36464,
  },
]);
```

I am trying to achieve this using Lodash in NuxtJs.

```
const RoomGroup = computed(() => {
  const GP = useGroupBy(RoomsPrices.value, "rg_ext");
  return GP;
});
```

how to match every key values inside rg_ext here and then returned a grouped array.
because here, i am getting all 4 objects in return rather than 2 objects with exact rg_ext.

Comment: whats the final output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if lodash can help you there, I would do it manually. Grouping works as always, i.e. for each item, go through the already created groups, and then either add  it to an existing group or start a new one. You just have to check for a full object instead of a single field:

```js
const roomPrices = [
  {
    rg_ext: {
      class: 5,
      quality: 0,
      sex: 0,
      bathroom: 2,
      bedding: 3,
      family: 0,
      capacity: 2,
      club: 0,
    },
    room_name: "2 Bedrooms Double Suite (full double bed)",
    cost: 10000,
    priceid: 15464,
  },
  {
    rg_ext: {
      class: 3,
      quality: 0,
      sex: 0,
      bathroom: 2,
      bedding: 2,
      family: 0,
      capacity: 3,
      club: 0,
    },
    room_name: "3 Bedrooms Double Suite (full double bed)",
    cost: 14000,
    priceid: 12464,
  },
  {
    rg_ext: {
      class: 3,
      quality: 0,
      sex: 0,
      bathroom: 2,
      bedding: 2,
      family: 0,
      capacity: 3,
      club: 0,
    },
    room_name: "3 Bedrooms Double Suite (full double bed)",
    cost: 14000,
    priceid: 12464,
  },
  {
    rg_ext: {
      class: 5,
      quality: 0,
      sex: 0,
      bathroom: 2,
      bedding: 3,
      family: 0,
      capacity: 2,
      club: 0,
    },
    room_name: "2 Bedrooms Double Suite (full double bed)",
    cost: 16300,
    priceid: 36464,
  },
]

const groupByObj = (arr, prop) => {
  const objectsMatch = (o1,o2) => {
    const k1 = Object.keys(o1)
    return k1.length === Object.keys(o2).length && k1.every(k => k in o2 && o1[k] === o2[k])
  }
  const res = []
  for(const item of arr){
    let group = res.find(g => objectsMatch(g[prop], item[prop]))
    if(!group){
      group = {[prop]: item[prop], items: []}
      res.push(group)
    }
    const {[prop]: _ , ...data} = item // just for readability of the example
    group.items.push(data)
  }
  return res
}

console.log(groupByObj(roomPrices, 'rg_ext'))
```

In Vue, you need to unpack the `ref` first, but the rest works the same.